# Cant fix 'Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a file controller in my asp net core web api for uploading images.  I used the sample provided by MS for large files (https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads#uploading-large-files-with-streaming).

From my Angular 5 front end I used a package to create a file upload control and it worked fine, but I didnt like the appearance so I've been trying to create my own version.

My code to upload looks like this:

```
uploadFile(file: File, relativePath: string): Observable<HttpEvent<ExternalFileResponse>> {
  const headers = this.getHeaders('multipart/form-data; boundary=fredfile;');
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, relativePath);

  formData.append('externalFileType', ExternalFileTypeEnum.image.toString());
  formData.append('subType', file.type);

  return this.httpClient.post<ExternalFileResponse>(
    environment.fileApiUrl + '/upload',
    formData,
    {
      headers: headers,
      observe: 'events',
      // params: this.httpRequestParams,
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Uploading any file gives me :

Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded

So also added this to my startup:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
  {
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
  });
```

But that didnt work.  (All the examples Ive seen for this are using services.AddMvc() but Im using services.AddMvcCore().  Im wondering if that is a problem?)

Chrome is not showing enough information to see the full request and I cant get (fecking) Fiddler to work on Windows 10.

Not sure what to try next.  Anyone here got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical, as soon as I post a question, I figure it out.

I removed the 'multipart/form-data;...' header and it works fine.  It looks like angular is clever (?) enough to add it's own content-type header and my one was just screwing things up.

Still curious about the FormOptions not working though...

Comment: When I remove it I face with `The info field is required.`. And if I remove only the boundary part the error would be `Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary.` I describe my issue in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706897/fetch-imagedata-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-patch)

Answer (score 4):

removing `request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");` also for me solved the problem!